# How to close FileWriter or diisable appending on action of button in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I have a class with a function which performs following task:

```
FileWriter fw = null;
        String filename= "abc.txt";
        try{
            fw = new FileWriter(filename,false);       
                for(Field f:fie)
                {
                    if(f.getName().equals("Xml"))
                        fw.write((String)f.get(t));             
                }                              
           }
        catch(IOException ioe){         
        }
        finally{
            fw.close();

        }
```

Which i call on Swing's button actionPerformed() function. I don't want it to append every time so i have used FileWriter(filename,false), but still it doesn't close file i guess, and keeps appending the text, every time i click button instead of overwriting it.

can you please suggest, what's wrong in this scenario ? 
I've closed file in finally with fw.close().

Is my guess write ? It's not closing file correctly right ? or is it something else related to Swing ?

Comment: can you doublecheck by debugging that the code you posted is actually getting executed? If I adapt your code into a test example it does exactly what you want.

Comment: yes it does, it keeps appending to the file. It only overwrites when i restart the app